# Sending array of String using URLEncoder.encode()?

Tags: java, url-encoding

I have two string arrays like this

```
String nearByColgs[]= {"461161","158179","218756","103456","184842","122560","118279"};
String interests[] ={"java","cricket"};
```

Now i want to send them using  URL.encode()

Problem is `URL.encode()` supports only String e.g.

```
 URL.encode("http://www.google.com","UTF-8");
```

What can be possible workaround to send the entire array say nearByColgs at once?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I want to pass the content in array. So that some other web application may decode URL and get the values !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
URL.encode(java.util.Arrays.toString( nearByColgs ) , "UTF-8");
```

Comment: You might have to convert nearByColgs array to JSON first and then encode the JSON String. using URL.encode

Answer (score 1):

I assume you not only want to send it using url encode but on the other side also decode it and have the same 2 variables of arrays of Strings back.

As you already found out you need to convert your array of Strings into a single String variable.

The other post show how to easily convert an array of String into a single String. But it doesn't show how to parse it back.

What you need is 2 separators (e.g. a comma and a semicolon), one is used to separate values within an array and the other to separate arrays.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append(nearByColgs[0]);
for (int i=1; i<nearByColgs.length;i++) {
    b.append(',').append(nearByColgs[i]);
}
b.append(';')
b.append(interests[0]);
for (int i=1; i<interests.length;i++) {
    b.append(',').append(interests[i]);
}
String concatenated = b.toString();
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(concatenated ,"UTF-8");
```

On the other side you then decode the encoded version again.

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
String[] subArrays = decoded.split(";")
```

and then you can recover your original data again as

```
String[] nearbyColgs = subArrays[0].split(",");
String interests = subArrays[1].split(",");
```

Of course, this only works if your original data doesn't contain one of the 2 separator characters used.

If it does, use other separators (like 'a' and 'b', or whatever you need) or use a more complex algorithm to concatenate strings and use a quoting scheme (like the CSV standard does).

Or the encoding logic looks for 2 characters not used and it addes these 2 characters as first characters in the string to encode, the decoding side receives an encoded string, decodes it and chops of the 2 first characters and use these as separators.

Note that the split function used accepts as argument a regular expression, so be careful with typicel regular expression characters like *.

Enjoy !